# To parse multiple files in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

Please correct my code, I cannot seem to open my file to parse.
  The error is this line `open(my $fh, $file) or die "Cannot open file, $!";`
  Cannot open file, No such file or directory at ./sample.pl line 28.

```
use strict;
my $dir = $ARGV[0];

my $dp_dpd = $ENV{'DP_DPD'};

my $log_dir = $ENV{'DP_LOG'};
my $xmlFlag = 0;
my @fileList = "";

my @not_proc_dir = `find $dp_dpd -type d -name "NotProcessed"`;

#print "@not_proc_dir\n";


foreach my $dir (@not_proc_dir) {
        chomp ($dir);
        #print "$dir\n";

    opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Couldn't open directory, $!";
    while ( my $file = readdir DIR) {
            next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
            next if (-d $file);
       #   print "$file\n";
            next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";
                    if ($file =~ /.xml$/ig) {
                     $xmlFlag = 1;
                     print "$file\n";
                     open(my $fh, $file) or die "Cannot open file, $!";
                    @fileList = <$fh>;
                    close $file;


                    }

            }
            closedir DIR;

}
```

Comment: unless *my @not_proc_dir = `find $dp_dpd -type d -name "NotProcessed"`;*
 you are using  `my $dir = $ARGV[0];`So you check your input should have files. And request you to pragma `use warnings`

Comment: Tip: `next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;` should be `next if $file =~ /^\.\.?\z/;`. `$` doesn't just match at the end of the string.

Comment: Tip `if ($file =~ /.xml$/ig)` should be `if ($file =~ /\.xml$/ig)`. `.` doesn't match just `.`.

Comment: Tip: `if ($file =~ /\.xml$/ig)` should be `if ($file =~ /\.xml$/i)`. `if (//g)` makes no sense and will cause subtle (hard to debug) errors.

Comment: Tip: `my @fileList = "";` should be `my @fileList;`. You are putting one empty string in the array.

Comment: Tip: `next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";` will never be true because of the earlier check.

Comment: Tip: `my $dir = $ARGV[0];` creates and initializes a variable that's never used.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting `readdir`'s [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html):

> If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a readdir, you'd better prepend the directory in question. Otherwise, because we didn't chdir there, it would have been testing the wrong file.

Your `open(my $fh, $file)` should therefore be `open my $fh, '<', "$dir/$file"` (note how I also added `'<'` as well: you should always use 3-argument open).

Your `next if (-d $file);` is also wrong and should be `next if -d "$dir/$file";`

---

Some additional remarks on your code:

- always add `use warnings` to your script (in addition to `use strict`, which you already have)
- use lexical file/directory handle rather than global ones. That is, do `opendir my $DH, $dir`, rather than `opendir DH, $dir`.
- properly indent your code (`if ($file =~ /.xml$/ig) {` is one level too deep; it makes it harder to read you code)
- `next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;` and `next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";` are redundant (even though not *technically* equivalent); I'd suggest using only the latter.
- the variable `$dir` defined in `my $dir = $ARGV[0];` is never used.